# Undocumented MySQL usage of the LIKE operator for multiple words

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Can't seem to find documentation on a particular formation of SQL using the LIKE operator.  Using MySQL, a typical query for multiple words using the LIKE operator may look like this:

```
SELECT * from table AS t WHERE t.col LIKE '%word1%' AND t.col LIKE '%word2%'
```

Although the following statement also works, the rows returned will vary depending on the order of the words in the query.  For example:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE col LIKE '%word1%' '%word2%'
```

executes without the AND boolean, but with different results from:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE col LIKE '%word2%' '%word1%'
```

My question is, what is actually happening when using this formation of the query instead of using boolean?

Comment: `'%word2%'` gets concatenated with  `'%word1%'`, giving you `'%word2%%word1%'` i.e. '<any chars>word2<anychars>word1<anychars>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html):

> Quoted strings placed next to each other are concatenated to a single
> string. The following lines are equivalent:
>
> `'a string'`
>
> `'a' ' ' 'string'`

So, what's happening is that `'%word1%' '%word2%'` is being interpreted as '%word1%%word2%'

Comment: @AlanTyson : Welcome to SO. If Matt answer your question please mark it accepted. Click [here, how accepting answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)